# many to many multithreading

Tags: operating-systems, threads, multi-tasking

In many to many multithreading model the processor threads are multiplexed to a lesser or equal number of kernel threads.
What exactly does it mean??
Does it mean that if a kernel is executing a blocking system call then the other threads will be shifted or multiplexed to other kernel threads??[image: what are they trying to convey through this image???]

Also is many to many a collection of many to one and one to one multithreads

Comment: It depends. In some systems you have to explicitly associate user threads to kernel threads and in that case when a kernel thread blocks all the user threads associated with it are stuck. In other systems this associated is more "fluid" and the user threads can move on different kernel threads, in such cases a blocked kernel thread doesn't block the remaining user threads.  If you want a more specific answer you have to tell us which precise definition/source you are using.

Comment: @Bakuriu, that sounds like a great answer to me!  Want to write it as an answer so we can upvote it?

Comment: @Bakuriu i am using Operating System Principles by Silberschatz, Galvin, Gagne

Comment: You can see this link
http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/68707/do-user-level-threads-take-advantage-of-multi-processing