# Do user level threads take advantage of multi processing?

Tags: operating-systems, threads, os-kernel

I asked this question here on stackoverflow, but maybe because of off-topic over there, it didn't received proper response.

---

Does user level threads take advantage of multiprocessing ? I read one such answer here. But, it's not clear though.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582876/what-does-it-mean-by-user-threads-cannot-take-advantage-of-multithreading-or-mu

And one other answer here says that it is possible

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791801/how-do-user-level-threads-ults-and-kernel-level-threads-klts-differ-with-reg

Am I missing something here with some important details ?

Comment: This seems implementation-dependent, so I'm not sure it's on-topic here.

Comment: The second link gives a decent answer.

Comment: @gnasher729 so is it true ? I mean what do you infer from this? I've searched google though, all of them say it cannot. Then, I can' t decode anything from 2nd link here .

Comment: @gnasher729 What I've inferred is that it's all implementation dependent working on 1:1 machines.

Comment: What are you confused about?  It all seems perfectly clear to me so I'm having a hard time guessing which part you're finding unclear.  If you use only user-level threads, then the answer is no.  if you use a combination of user-level threads and kernel-level threads, then the answer is yes... as explained in those answers.  I'm not sure what the question is.  Do you understand how user-level threads and kernel-level threads work?  Maybe what would help you would be to spend some more time reading about them and how they work?

Comment: If user-level threads are implemented to take advantage of multi-processing, then they take advantage of multi-processing. If user-level threads are implemented *not* to take advantage of multi-processing, then they do *not* take advantage of multi-processing.